# Cache for mesh objects

Tags: c++, c++17, cache, polymorphism

I'm creating a cache system for an object (`Mesh`) that is expensive to create. A `Mesh` can be created using a small amount of information in a hashable key (`MeshKey`). There are multiple methods of creating meshes, and the key must identify which method is being used and supply the parameters to the creation function. The client code must be able to add creation methods. The cache looks like this:

```cpp
class MeshCache {
public:
    Mesh get(const MeshKey& key) const {
        return _cache.count(key) ? _cache.at(key) : _cache.try_emplace(key, _create(key)).first->second;
    }

private:
    Mesh _create(const MeshKey& key) const {
        return ...;
    }

    mutable std::unordered_map<MeshKey, Mesh> _cache;
};
```

Essentially, the cache is handed a `MeshKey` from which to identify and return a specific `Mesh`. If it doesn't yet exist, create it and cache it. This means the key represents both the method that should be used to create the mesh and the parameters used to create it (for example, one key could represent a sphere mesh with a specific radius, another a box with three side lengths).

The big problem is `MeshCache::_create`. If the set of creation methods were known, I could map an index to a generator function, or `std::visit` a `std::variant` of all the possible `MeshKey` types. As the user must be able to add their own creation modes, I decided polymorphism was the way to go:

```cpp
struct _MeshKey {
    virtual size_t hash() const = 0;
    virtual bool operator==(const _MeshKey& rhs) const = 0;
    virtual Mesh create() const = 0;
    virtual std::unique_ptr<_MeshKey> clone() const = 0;
};

class MeshKey {
public:
    MeshKey(std::unique_ptr<_MeshKey>&& x): key(std::move(x)) {}

    MeshKey(const MeshKey& other): key(other.key->clone()) {}

    size_t hash() const {
        return key->hash();
    }

    bool operator==(const MeshKey& rhs) const {
        return *key == *rhs.key;
    }

    Mesh create() const {
        return key->create();
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<_MeshKey> key;
};

namespace std {
    template <> struct hash<MeshKey> {
        size_t operator()(const MeshKey& x) const noexcept { return x.hash(); }
    };
}
```

`MeshCache::_create` could then simply return `key.create()`.

This lets me create new types of keys like this:

```cpp
struct SphereMeshKey: public _MeshKey {
    SphereMeshKey(float radius): radius(radius) {}

    float radius;

    size_t hash() const override { return std::hash<float>()(radius); }

    bool operator==(const _MeshKey& rhs) const override {
        if (typeid(*this) != typeid(rhs)) {
            return false;
        }
        auto obj = static_cast<const SphereMeshKey&>(rhs);
        return radius == obj.radius;
    }

    Mesh create() const override {
        return ...; // Generate sphere mesh
    }

    std::unique_ptr<_MeshKey> clone() const override {
        return std::make_unique<SphereMeshKey>(radius);
    }
};
```

Unfortunately, this resulted in some ugly coupling between the values in the key itself and the object creation -- if creating the object required the use of other objects, those must typically be passed into the derived key's constructor. My first several attempts at decoupling resulted in some unattractive use of RTTI and two sets of polymorphic classes (keys and generators) which had to be authored by the client and then *registered* with the cache object. This complicated the logic and was generally a messy solution.

The problems I see with this design are:

- Heavy coupling between the mesh generation code and the mesh identification (keying) code
- Relying on a polymorphic structure to do the job of a map key (which usually should behave like a POD) requires prototype pattern (`clone` function) and heap allocation (dynamically sized key)
- While I imagine some use of RTTI will likely make its way into the final code, my use of `typeid` in the equality operator felt repetitive and likely to create bugs down the road

Is there a more elegant solution? I generally favor readability and maintainability over performance until profiling reveals issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I generally favor readability and maintainability over performance until profiling reveals issues.

That's a very good mindset to have. I think the lack of elegance in your code comes from the fact that the classes have too many or not the right responsibilities. For example, `MeshKey` looks like a base class but it's actually a wrapper around a `std::unique_ptr` to a concrete key object, and `_MeshKey` is the actual base. Derived classes should also not have to worry about being compared against different derived types. Keep each class as simple as possible.

You explored using `std::variant` and using polymorphism, but you missed another possibility: just make the cache itself templated on the key type. This simplifies the cache, as it then only has to deal with one specific type.
Consider:

```
class MeshCache {
public:
    template <typename Key>
    static const Mesh& get(const Key& key) {
        auto& cache = _cache<Key>;

        if (auto it = cache.find(key); it != cache.end()) {
            return it->second;
        } else {
            return cache.try_emplace(key, key.create()).first->second;
        }
    }

private:
    template <typename Key>
    inline static std::unordered_map<Key, Mesh> _cache;
};
```

Now you no longer need derived classes nor `std::unique_ptr`s. So `SphereMeshKey` becomes:

```
struct SphereMeshKey {
    float radius;
    Mesh create() const {
        return ...;
    }
};
```

And the code that uses the cache will look like:

```
auto& earthMesh = MeshCache::get(SphereMeshKey{6.371e6});
```

The real magic is in the `inline` keyword used to declare `_cache`: it will ensure a `_cache<Key>` is instantiated for every type `Key` you use, and if multiple translation units cause the same `_cache<Key>` to be instantiated, the linker will merge them into one.

The above code has two other optimizations: `get()` returns a *reference* to a `Mesh` instead of making a copy of one, and it also uses `find()` instead of `count()`+`at()`, the latter would search the map twice instead of once.

Comment: That `inline static` template member is nutty. When did C++ add that feature? :o

Comment: @user673679 In C++17 :)

Comment: Interesting. This is essentially the singleton pattern, no? It's impossible to have multiple `Mesh` caches for instance. Handling this with templates was something I'd considered, but couldn't quite get looking nice. I've never seen `inline static` from your implementation, thanks for teaching me something today!

Comment: Yes, it effectively is a singleton, which probably is what you want anyway for a cache. You could make the whole `class MeshCache` a template (on an `enum` type for example) and make multiple caches that way.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Mesh get(const MeshKey& key) const {
>     return _cache.count(key) ? _cache.at(key) : _cache.try_emplace(key, _create(key)).first->second;
> }
> ```

Some things:

- `count` looks up the key in the map, then `at` does the same lookup a second time.
- We should add some error handling, in case `try_emplace` fails - even an `assert` would do.
- I don't think there's a good reason to hide the fact that `get()` might change the cache. The function shouldn't be `const`, and the `_cache` member variable shouldn't be `mutable`.
- Should we really be returning a `Mesh` by value (i.e. copying it) instead of returning a `const&` or even a pointer?

---

```
struct _MeshKey {
...

class MeshKey {
...

struct SphereMeshKey: public _MeshKey {
...
```

Hmm. I would call this a `MeshGenerator` instead of a `MeshKey`, as I think that's its primary purpose. It seems like the user always has to pass the appropriate `MeshKey` (or `MeshGenerator`) into the `get()` function... so I'm not sure there's a reason to store the entire generator object inside the cache. We could probably use a simple `std::unordered_map<std::size_t, Mesh>` instead.

I think what's missing is to ensure that the generator class contributes to the resulting `std::size_t` hash value, like so:

```
struct MeshGenerator {
    virtual ~MeshGenerator() { } // note: important!
    virtual std::size_t hash() const = 0;
    virtual Mesh create() const = 0;
};

struct SphereMeshGenerator : MeshGenerator {
    
    SphereMeshGenerator(float radius): _radius(radius) { }
    
    std::size_t hash() const override {
        
        using std::literals;
        auto const hashGenerator = std::hash<std::string_view>()("sphere"sv);
        auto const hashRadius = std::hash<float>()(_radius);
        
        return combineHashes(hashGenerator, hashRadius);
    }
    
    ...
    
};
```

where `combineHashes()` is something like this:

```
inline std::size_t combineHashes(std::size_t a, std::size_t b) {
    return a ^ (b + 0x9e3779b9 + (a << 6) + (a >> 2)); // note: algorithm pilfered from boost hash_combine
}
```

So to use it we'd do something like:

```
    auto cache = MeshCache();
    auto const generator = SphereMeshGenerator(1.f);
    auto const mesh = cache.get(generator);
```

and `get()` might be:

```
    Mesh const& get(MeshGenerator const& gen) {
        
        auto const key = gen.hash();
        
        if (auto const entry = _cache.find(key); entry != _cache.end())
            return entry->second;
        
        auto mesh = gen.create();
        
        auto [entry, inserted] = _cache.insert({ key, std::move(mesh) });
        assert(inserted);
        
        return entry->second;
    }
```

Note that inheritance might not be necessary here unless you need to store different `MeshGenerator` types in the same container. Otherwise we could make `get()` a template function instead.

(We could even split the key and the generator function into separate `std::size_t` and `std::function<Mesh(void)>` parameters, if we really wanted too).

---

(Or do what G Sleipen said. I did not know that was a thing.)

Comment: The problem of hashes is that they are not guaranteed to be unique. You must account for the possibility of two different `MeshGenerator`s to return the same hash value. This is why `std::unordered_map` requires both `std::hash()` and an `operator==()` for the key type it stores.

Comment: A lot of good catches, somehow a virtual destructor on the base class had completely slipped my mind. `find` instead of `count`/`at` is also a very good point. Not sure about the mutability, at some point down the line, the cache will have to be mutable, because the mutations are opaque to some of my higher-level classes where it doesn't make sense to drop `const`-ness.